# How do I access an access array item by index in handlebars?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I am trying to specify the index of an item in an array within a handlebars template:

```
{
  people: [
    {"name":"Yehuda Katz"},
    {"name":"Luke"},
    {"name":"Naomi"}
  ]
}
```

using this:

```
<ul id="luke_should_be_here">
{{people[1].name}}
</ul>
```

If the above is not possible, how would I write a helper that could access a spefic item within the array?

Answer (score 369, accepted):

The following, *with an additional dot before the index*, works just as expected. Here, the square brackets are optional when the index is followed by another property:

```
{{people.[1].name}}
{{people.1.name}}
```

However, the square brackets are *required* in:

```
{{#with people.[1]}}
  {{name}}
{{/with}}
```

In the latter, using the index number without the square brackets would get one:

```
Error: Parse error on line ...:
...     {{#with people.1}}                
-----------------------^
Expecting 'ID', got 'INTEGER'
```

As an aside: the brackets are (also) used for [segment-literal syntax](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/expressions.html#literal-segments), to refer to actual identifiers (not index numbers) that would otherwise be invalid. More details in [What is a valid identifier?](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars-site/issues/26)

(Tested with Handlebars in YUI.)

### 2.xx Update

You can now use the `get` helper for this:

```
(get people index)
```

although if you get an error about index needing to be a string, do:

```
(get people (concat index ""))
```

Comment: This should be the answer because it is more thorough than the selected answer. Requiring square brackets when the index is at the end had me stuck for a while!

Comment: this did the trick! thanks... the chosen answer above this didn't, please mark this as the correct.

Comment: The `{{#with people.1}}` solution worked for me, using `com.github.jknack:handlebars:4.1.2`.

Comment: trying to find a way to adjust the index number so I can check a value from the previous item in the loop against this one. Any ideas?

Answer (score 462):

Try this:

```
<ul id="luke_should_be_here">
{{people.1.name}}
</ul>
```

Comment: I'm getting `Expecting 'ID'` error with {{user.links.websites.1}} or {{user.links.websites.0}}

Comment: @OlivierLalonde, I had to use something like `{{ websites.[0] }}` .

Comment: Indeed, @Matt, that is not just some lucky format, but is kind of the documented syntax. (See my answer.)

Comment: For ember.js, I had to do something like `people.content.1.name`

Comment: This does not work with Meteor.js. See @Arjan's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13704081/245540) below instead

Comment: @lukemh A LOT of stuff in handlebars is either poorly documented or not documented anywhere. Yayyyy....

Comment: thanks - hunted all over for a way to use [0] notation, now know that it's delegated to a weird dot notation

Comment: how to access if key is dynamic.For eg if in this the ondex value is a variable. i.e  {{people.var1.name}}  ?????

Comment: @user3711185, see [julesbou's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8044219/how-do-i-access-an-access-array-item-by-index-in-handlebars/37333480#37333480) and the references it links to.

Comment: This solution worked for me, using `com.github.jknack:handlebars:4.1.2`.

Comment: this doesn't work when you are in the each loop ;-(

Answer (score 34):

```
{{#each array}}
  {{@index}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Awesome, This is the correct answer. @index will give you the position in the array.

Comment: Correct answer, can anybody help me how can I print index starting with 1. By default it starts from 0.

Answer (score 20):

If undocumented features aren't your game, the same can be accomplished here:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('index_of', function(context,ndx) {
  return context[ndx];
});
```

Then in a template

```
{{#index_of this 1}}{{/index_of}}
```

I wrote the above before I got a hold of

```
this.[0]
```

I can't see one getting too far with handlebars without writing your own helpers.

Answer (score 16):

**If you want to use dynamic variables**

This won't work:

```
{{#each obj[key]}}
...
{{/each}}
```

You need to do:

```
{{#each (lookup obj key)}}
...
{{/each}}
```

see [handlebars lookup helper](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/builtin-helpers.html#lookup) and [handlebars subexpressions](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/expressions.html#subexpressions).

Comment: lookup worked here, even with an index an list from a previous block :  `{{lookup ../../btnPercentages @../index}}`

Answer (score 10):

Please try this, if you want to fetch first/last.

```
{{#each list}}

    {{#if @first}}
        <div class="active">
    {{else}}
        <div>
    {{/if}}

{{/each}}


{{#each list}}

    {{#if @last}}
        <div class="last-element">
    {{else}}
        <div>
    {{/if}}

{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 10):

While you are looping in an array with `each` and if you want to access another array in the context of the current item you do it like this.

Here is the example data.

```
[
  {
    name: 'foo',
    attr: [ 'boo', 'zoo' ]
  },
  {
    name: 'bar',
    attr: [ 'far', 'zar' ]
  }
]
```

Here is the handlebars to get the first item in `attr` array.

```
{{#each player}}
  <p> {{this.name}} </p>

  {{#with this.attr}}
    <p> {{this.[0]}} </p>
  {{/with}}

{{/each}}
```

This will output

```
<p> foo </p>
<p> boo </p>

<p> bar </p>
<p> far </p>
```

Comment: if the attr array has different number of elements for different objects then what will be the process to iterate through it ? for example : 
[
  {
    name: 'foo',
    attr: [ 'boo', 'zoo' ]
  },
  {
    name: 'bar',
    attr: [ 'far', 'zar','sar ]
  }
]

then how are you going to show all the attr for every objects of the array ?

Comment: i didn't try it but i assume in {{#with this.attr}} `this` would work instead of `this.[0]`

Answer (score 1):

The following syntax can also be used if the array is not named (just the array is passed to the template):

```
  <ul id="luke_should_be_here">
  {{this.1.name}}
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I wanted to access an array inside a custom helper like so,

```
{{#ifCond arr.[@index] "foo" }}
```

Which did not work, but the answer suggested by @julesbou worked.

Working code:

```
{{#ifCond (lookup arr @index) "" }}
```

Hope this helps! Cheers.

Comment: how would you adjust the index value in this case? ie I want to compare a value from index and index - 1 (doesn't work). Thanks.