# Getting the last element from a JSON array in a Handlebars template

Tags: json, handlebars.js, client-side-templating

So, I found that array elements can be accessed in Handlebars using:

```
{{myArray.2.nestedObject}} and {{myArray.0.nestedObject}}
```

..to get the third and first elements for instance. ([handlebars-access-array-item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8044219/handlebars-access-array-item))

Is there a way to get the **last element** from an array?
I tried creating a helper for it:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("lastElement", function(array) {
  return array.last();  //Array.prototype extension
});
```

...and calling it as follows in the template:

```
{{lastElement myArray}} or even {{lastElement myArray.lastElement nestedArray}}
```

Sadly, this doesn't work. Helper functions return strings apparently. What I need is a way to be able to do this even with multi-dimensional arrays.

Comment: Note that you could use `{{myArray.[2].nestedObject}}` for the first example. The [same segment-literal notation](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars-site/issues/26) might help for a variable index number?

Answer (score 7):

Should work, I've tested it.

Template:

```
{{last foo}}
```

Data:

```
{foo : [1,2,3,4,5,6]}
```

Helper:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("last", function(array) {
  return array[array.length-1];
});
```

Answer (score -1):

The above piece of code works fine in all the cases. But if the array passed if a null array, possibility of the handlebar function throwing error is there. Instead perform a null check and then return the value accordingly.