# HandlebarsJS How to get last item of array

Tags: handlebars.js

I want to fetch the last item of my JSON file. So I took a look at [Getting the last element from a JSON array in a Handlebars template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10755092/getting-the-last-element-from-a-json-array-in-a-handlebars-template) and tried to implement it. So far it gives me the number of the last entry but I need the options as well but dont know how to do it?

This is from the example mentioned

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("last", function(array, options) {
    return array[array.length-1];
});
```

I tried to do:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("last", function(array, options) {
    if (array[array.length-1]) return options.fn(this);
    return options.inverse(this);
});
```

My JSON files structure is:

```
releases: [{
    "title" : "some title",
    "releaseDate" : "2014-08-04"
    },
    "services": [{
         "name" : "spotify",
         "link" : "some link"
     }, 
     {
         "name" : "itunes",
         "link" : "some link"
    }]
  ]
```

so my Handlebars template looks like:

```
{{#each releases}}
    {{#last releaseDate}}
        {{#each services}}
            {{#equal name "Spotify" }}
                <a href="{{link}}"></a>
            {{/equal}}
            {{#equal name "Itunes" }}
                <a href="{{link}}"></a>
            {{/equal}}
        {{/each}}
    {{/last}}
{{/each}}
```

But its not working, it displays an empty DIV

please help?

Comment: Could you please post a more complete version of the JSON file structure? e.g. a full sample of what you're using?

Comment: @SargoDarya updated the json, please check above

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Handlebars already has `@first` and `@last` pseudo-variables. See docs on [iterations](http://handlebarsjs.com/#iteration) and [built-in helpers](http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html).

Example use case:

`textArray = ["First", "N-1", "Last"]`

`<span>{{#each textArray}}{{#if @last}}{{this}}{{/if}}{{/each}}</span>`

Result: `<span>Last</span>`

Answer (score 0):

I would use an iterator helper for this.

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('layoutReleases', function (rows, options) {
    var buffer = [], lastRow;
    if (rows && rows.length > 0) {
        lastRow = rows[rows.length-1];
        buffer.push(options.fn(lastRow));
    }
    return buffer.join('');
});
```

Template:

```
{{#layoutReleases releases}}
    {{releaseDate}}
    {{#each services}}
       {{#equal name "Spotify" }}
            <a href="{{link}}"></a>
       {{/equal}}
       {{#equal name "Itunes" }}
            <a href="{{link}}"></a>
       {{/equal}}
    {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```