# Handlebars array length -1

Tags: javascript, arrays, ember.js, handlebars.js

is there a way to get an index of an array within a handlebar template and I want to get the last value in the array and call a . property on it

```
{{currentRevision.computedRoutingNodes.length-1.numberOfReviewDays}}
```

computedRoutingNodes is an array of objects

I know i can get an index like

```
{{currentRevision.computedRoutingNodes.1.numberOfReviewDays}}
```

but I want to get the last value dynamically

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting the last element from a JSON array in a Handlebars template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10755092/getting-the-last-element-from-a-json-array-in-a-handlebars-template)

Comment: @McGarnagle I think this is a somehow different operation since the op is looking to get a property of the last item and not the last item itself. It seems like you should be able to adapt the code that you posted though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{{currentRevision.computedRoutingNodes.lastObject.numberOfReviewDays}}` will work if you're using Ember.js.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a helper:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('propAtLengthRelativeIndex', function (arr, index, prop) {
    return new Handlebars.SafeString(arr[arr.length + ~~index][prop]);
});
```

And then call it like this:

```
{{propAtLengthRelativeIndex currentRevision.computedRoutingNodes '-1' 'numberOfReviewDays'}}
```