# Using objects with numeric properties in handlebars.js

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

Is it possible to use Handlebars with objects that have numeric keys?

For example:

```
var str = "<div>{{apples}}</div>",
    tmpl = Handlebars.compile(str);

tmpl({apples: "works!"}); // returns "<div>works!</div>"
```

Works great, but

```
var str = "<div>{{4}}</div>",
    tmpl = Handlebars.compile(str);

tmpl({4: "works!"}); 
// returns Error: Parse error on line 1: <div>{{4}}</div> -------^ Expecting 'DATA', 'ID', got 'INTEGER'
```

I was unable to find any references to this when searching, and I have not yet explored the source code.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

So after looking around further, I found I needed to wrap the number in square brackets, like:

`{{[4]}}`

Here's a link to a semi-relevant SO question [How do I access an access array item by index in handlebars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8044219/handlebars-access-array-item)

The above link refers to accessing array items, but the answer gave me the idea to try wrapping the numeric path in square brackets.

Comment: As an aside: the Handlebars author calls those brackets the [segment-literal syntax](http://handlebarsjs.com/expressions.html), to refer to actual identifiers (not index numbers) that would otherwise be invalid. More details in [What is a valid identifier?](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars-site/issues/26)

Comment: Nice! Works with Meteor JS Blaze templates too, as I just found out thanks to this.