# How to access included Sequelize model with Handlebars.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js, handlebars.js

I have two associated models I am trying to display data for:

```
    Articles.hasMany(QuizAttempts);
    QuizAttempts.belongsTo(Articles);
    const attempts = await Articles.findAll(
        { include: QuizAttempts, raw: true, all: true},
        { where: { user_id: 13 }}
    );
```

This query displays the following:

```
[
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'This is a test cardiology article.',
    category: 2,
    content: '#Test article\r\n' +
      '\r\n' +
      'This is a test cardiology article.This is a test cardiology article.This is a test cardiology article.This is a test cardiology article.This is a test cardiology article.This is a test cardiology article.This is a test cardiology article.',
    active: 1,
    level: 'Advanced',
    likes: 0,
    createdAt: 2022-09-14T14:08:34.000Z,
    updatedAt: 2022-09-14T14:08:34.000Z,
    'QuizAttempts.id': 1,
    'QuizAttempts.user_id': '13',
    'QuizAttempts.articleId': '4',
    'QuizAttempts.category': 1,
    'QuizAttempts.score': '1',
    'QuizAttempts.createdAt': 2022-09-16T15:12:12.000Z,
    'QuizAttempts.updatedAt': 2022-09-16T15:43:26.000Z,
    'QuizAttempts.ArticleId': '4'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'This is a test cardiology article.',
    category: 2,
    content: '#Test article\r\n' +
      '\r\n' +
      'This is a test cardiology article.This is a test cardiology article.This is a test cardiology article.This is a test cardiology article.This is a test cardiology article.This is a test cardiology article.This is a test cardiology article.',
    active: 1,
    level: 'Advanced',
    likes: 0,
    createdAt: 2022-09-14T14:08:34.000Z,
    updatedAt: 2022-09-14T14:08:34.000Z,
    'QuizAttempts.id': 2,
    'QuizAttempts.user_id': '13',
    'QuizAttempts.articleId': '4',
    'QuizAttempts.category': 1,
    'QuizAttempts.score': '5',
    'QuizAttempts.createdAt': 2022-09-16T20:21:22.000Z,
    'QuizAttempts.updatedAt': 2022-09-16T20:21:22.000Z,
    'QuizAttempts.ArticleId': '4'
  }
]
```

I can access the Article data just fine and display that on the page however, I cannot get the QuizAttempt data to show. Here's what I've tried:

```
{{#each attempts}}
{{name}}
{{level}}

{{QuizAttempts.id}}
{{/each}}
```

I'm sure it's a simple fix and I'm just confued. I'm new to Sequelize.

Comment: It's not related to sequelize. Your property just have to be used with `[]` [Using objects with numeric properties in handlebars.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14365665/using-objects-with-numeric-properties-in-handlebars-js)

Comment: Thanks! I knew the answer would be simple. `{{[QuizAttempts.id}}` got everything going good. :)