# Handlebars Array Element on This

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I've setup a simple handlebars template displays images from records from a model.  The following works as expected and uses the imageURL on each item to display the image.

```
{{#each this}}

<img {{bindAttr src="imageURL"}} >

{{/each}}
```

However, I also want to display the first image in the set of records.  Going by [How do I access an access array item by index in handlebars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8044219/handlebars-access-array-item) I added the following with no luck.

```
<img {{bindAttr src="this.0.imageURL"}} >
```

I also tried the following with no luck either.

```
{{#with this.[0]}}
<img {{bindAttr src="imageURL"}} >
{{/with}}
```

Any ideas?

Notables: Ember 1.2.0, Handlebars 1.2.0, jQuery 1.10.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that this doesn't work is because `this` refers to the `ArrayController` that rendered this template. Now you're probably wondering why `{{#each this}}` works. That's because Ember will get the `content` property of the array controller, which is an `Ember.Array` containing the actual image objects.

Please read this documentation on Ember.ArrayController: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayController.html.

In order to display the first image you could extend your controller like so:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  firstImage: function() {
    this.get('firstObject');
  }.property('[]')
});
```

You'll have to use `this.get('firstObject')` since Ember.Array works a bit different than a normal js array. Here you'll find some more documentation: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Array.html#property_firstObject.

Displaying the first image in your template becomes easy now:

```
<img {{bindAttr src="firstImage.imageURL"}} />
```

Comment: Thanks that helps.  I also find the following also works.


    <img {{bindAttr src="firstObject.imageURL"}} />

Answer (score 0):

If you go to [Try Handlebars.js](http://tryhandlebarsjs.com) and add to **Handlebars Template** `{{this.0.img}}` and to **Context (JavaScript literal or JSON)**

```
[{
   img: 'path/to/img'
}, {
   img: 'path/to/img'
}]
```

Its work. Maybe problem in your helper.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work:

Template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  <ul>
  {{#each this}}
    <img {{bindAttr src="this.0.imageURL"}} >
  {{/each}}
  </ul>
</script>
```

JS:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return [
             [
               {imageURL: "http://placehold.it/100x100"},
               {imageURL: "http://placekitten.com/200/200"}
             ], 
             [
               {imageURL: "http://placehold.it/200x200"},
               {imageURL: "http://placekitten.com/100/100"}
             ],
             [
               {imageURL: "http://placehold.it/300x300"},
               {imageURL: "http://placekitten.com/300/300"}
             ]
           ];
  }
});
```

[JSBin example](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/UTAgIQUh/1/edit)