# I want to call specific instances of an object using handlebars ex.{{ object.someAttribute 2 }}

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

Object 1 and Object 2 are all a part of an Objects (array), and each object has someAttribute: DS.attr('string');

So the array is only two objects for this example, and I want to the value of someAttribut

I know how to loop through each Object with {{#each}} **but I want one object called, not a list of all of them**.

Do I call `{{ object.someAttribute 2 }}`, where i state the object, the attribute i want displayed and then its ID?

I want to know how to call this object and its attributes on **any** page.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: is object an array? or is the scope supposedly an array, I'm not sure where we're getting the 3rd object from.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I've updated the question to be much more clear. I hope thus helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To call specific item / object of an array in handlebars, use

`{{objects.[1].someAttribute}}` to access the `someAttribute` property of the second object in the array.

example,
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/xagewugi/1/edit

**hbs**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  using <b>\{{each}}</b> helper
    <ul>
    {{#each item in model}}
      <li>id: {{item.id}}<br/>
  someAttr1: {{item.someAttr1}}</li>
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
  calling an object <b>directly</b><br/>
  this is the first object's attributes:<br/>
  id: {{model.[0].id}}<br/>
  someAttr1: {{model.[0].someAttr1}}
  </script>
```

**js**

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return [
      Em.Object.create({id:1,someAttr1:"attribute of 1"}),
      Em.Object.create({id:2,someAttr1:"attribute of 2"}),
      Em.Object.create({id:3,someAttr1:"attribute of 3"}),
      Em.Object.create({id:4,someAttr1:"attribute of 4"})
    ];
  }
});
```

*also check out this [How do I access an access array item by index in handlebars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8044219/handlebars-access-array-item)*