# How to access an item in the array using a parent index?

Tags: handlebars.js

How to access an item in the array using a parent index?

**I want to something like this:
  this.[../index].[1]**

But no output is displayed. I tried displaying via {{../index}} and it works. How come when I put it inside the [] to use, it's not working. Does anyone have an idea?

Data:

`{ values: [[1,1],[2,2]],
  options: { english: [[1,'one'],[2,'two']], spanish: [[1,'uno],[2,'dos']]}
}`

Code:
`{{#each values}}
    {{#each options}}
         this.[../index].[1]
     {{/each}}
  {{/each}}`

The intended display is this:

1   1   one uno

2   2   two dos

Comment: Found a solution in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8044219/handlebars-access-array-item/13704081#13704081
: 
Handlebars.registerHelper('index_of', function(context,ndx) {
  return context[ndx];
});

But I'm leaving this question open since I still want to know why it isn't possible.

Comment: is not `{{@index}}` working?