# Why does handlebars use dot bracket notation for accessing arrays by index?

Tags: javascript, arrays, handlebars.js

Handlebars is a JS library, so why does it need a dot before array index values such as 
    `data.array.[0]`
instead of 
    `data.array[0]`

Comment: It must be a preprocessor of JS, because that's not valid JS syntax.

Comment: i may have been wrong to call it a library instead of a preprocessor, but i still don't understand the design choice to use this 'dot bracket' notation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The square brackets are "[segment-literal notation](http://handlebarsjs.com/expressions.html#basic-blocks)":

> To reference a property that is not a valid identifier, you can use segment-literal notation:
>
> ```
> {{#each articles.[10].[#comments]}}
>  <h1>{{subject}}</h1>
>  <div>
>    {{body}}
>  </div>
> {{/each}}
> ```

As you can see, you use square brackets to "quote" identifier that might be problematic as bare identifiers in an expression path, like `#comments`. This category of problematic identifiers also includes identifiers that are integers (as array indices are) when they come at the end of an path; see [this answer on How do I access an access array item by index in handlebars?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13704081/710446)

As for why they simply didn't do away with the dot entirely when using square-bracket syntax for problematic identifiers (e.g., `foo[#comments]`), I can't say for sure, but it does seem nicely consistent for readability to ensure that the segments of a path are always separated by periods.

Comment: this is exactly the answer i was looking for. Thanks a lot for the write up and explanation.

Answer (score 0):

`Handlebars.js` is an enhanced version of `Mustache` library. I would guess it uses similar grammar for parsing as `Mustache` so this *dot-notation* must somehow come from there.