# Expecting 'ID', got 'NUMBER'

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I have following data in `json`

```
"ICON":{
    "144":"https://example.com/bubble-academy.jpg",
    "228":"https://example.com/bubble-academy.jpg",
    "72":"https://example.com/bubble-academy.jpg",
    "152":"https://example.com/bubble-academy.jpg",
    "130":"https://example.com/bubble-academy.jpg",
    "120":"https://example.com/bubble-academy.jpg",
    "32":"https://example.com/bubble-academy.jpg"
}
```

In handlebars, I am trying to access property `32` like following.

```
<img src="{{ ICON.32 }}">
```

and I get following error

```
Module build failed: Error: Parse error on line 5:
..."{{ mediaFiles.ICON.32  }}">        <sp
-----------------------^
Expecting 'ID', got 'NUMBER'
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Not knowing handlbars, I guess `{{ ICON[32] }}` ? *edit:* Ah, should be `ICON.[32]`. Docs: http://handlebarsjs.com/expressions.html

Comment: Already tried that one no avail yeet.

Comment: with `ICON.[32]`, it worked.

Comment: Uriel was right, unfortunately they deleted their answer :-/

Comment: What's the lesson learned here for everybody? Always read the [documentation](http://handlebarsjs.com/expressions.html).

Comment: Almost a duplicate of [How do I access an access array item by index in handlebars?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8044219/218196c)

Comment: @FelixKling: Maybe not even almost. (Wow, what weird syntax.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because you are using a number as the property name, try using this instead:

`<img src="{{ ICON.[32] }}">`

Comment: It says `Expecting 'ID', got 'INVALID'`

Comment: `ICON.[32]` ought ti be `ICON[32]`

Answer (score 1):

Here is also an interesting case to confuse people:
(this is how statically generated wordpress forms look)

```
Input
{
    "body" : {
        'input_2.2': 'Mrs.',
        'input_2.3': 'Cynthia',
        'input_2.6': 'Winterbottom',   
        'input_6': 'Professor',
  }
}
```

This template results in blanks

```
<p>Form submission</p>
  <p>{{body.input_2.[2]}} {{body.input_2.[3]}} {{body.input_2.[6]}}</p>
  <p>{{body.input_6}}</p>

Result:
<p></p>
<p>Professor</p>
```

Apparently since all of the numeric entries do not exist... you can not simply bracket them... you must group the whole subpath at once

```
Proper template:
<p>Form submission</p>
  <p>{{body.[input_2.2]}} {{body.[input_2.3]}} {{body.[input_2.6]}}</p>
  <p>{{body.input_6}}</p>
```

This was found via trial and error... could not find proper documentation explaining this