# Calling a Specific custom_field BigCommerce Stencil

Tags: handlebars.js, shopify, bigcommerce

Currently I can get custom fields all or none. Like this

`{{#each product.custom_fields}}
      {{ id }} : {{ name }} : {{ value }}
{{/each}}`

but what if i want to call just one of them by id or name like the below. Is there a way to do that with stencil or otherwise?

`{{product.custom_fields.id:4.name}}`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the existing {{if}} helper to accomplish this

```
{{#if display_name '===' 'material'}}
    {{#each product.custom_fields}}
        {{id}} : {{name}} : {{value}}   
    {{/each}
{{/if}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can select a list item by id. `{{product.custom_fields.id.4.name}}`, however, if you want to select by name you'll need to implement a conditional as @alyss suggested.

See: [How do I access an access array item by index in handlebars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8044219/how-do-i-access-an-access-array-item-by-index-in-handlebars)