# Mongoose deep population (specific field)

Tags: mongoose

I have three models. And i need to get the admin group name of a user

**User**

```
  var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    // ...
    roles: {
      admin: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Admin' }, // path 1
    },
 });
```

**Admin**

```
  var adminSchema= new mongoose.Schema({
    // ...
    groups: [{ type: String, ref: 'AdminGroup' }], // path 2
  });
```

**AdminGroup**

```
  var adminGroupSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    // ...
    name: { type: String, default: '' }, // need to get this field
  });
```

In Mongoose

```
User.findById(req.user._id)
    .populate({path: 'roles.admin', populate:{ path: 'groups'}})
      .exec(function (err, adminGroups) {...}
```

When I try to call in my template `{{adminGroups.name}}` it returns the `name` of `Admin` model, which also has a `name` field, instead of `AdminGroup` model.
I am usung Mongoose 4.9.0 so it must have support for deep population. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `findById` and populating its fields.

You're not getting back `adminGroups` but ONE `user` who *may* have `roles.admin` that *may* contain an array of `groups`. I use the word *may* because those other fields might not be populated if they do not exist. However, you'll still get back one `User` document, if there is one.

```
User.findById(req.user._id).populate({
    path: 'roles.admin', 
    populate: { 
        path: 'groups'
    }
}).exec(function (err, user) {
    console.log(err, user); // see what it prints out
    console.log(user.roles.admin.groups[0].name);
});
```

And shouldn't it be `AdminGroup` instead of `AccountGroup` in your schema definition?

Comment: the 1st it prints out whole User document with   `groups: [Object],` the second is now returnig Root (what i needed). So the ploblem is with templates? How shild I call it there?

Comment: @ASem Pass the `user` object to your view and do `{{user.roles.admin.groups[0].name}}` maybe?

Comment: It returns me an error ` Expecting 'ID', got 'INVALID'  ` I im using Handlebars.

Comment: @ASem According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8044689/1022914), it should be `user.roles.admin.groups.0.name` or `user.roles.admin.groups.[0].name`.

Comment: Wow thanks you helped me a lot. That was really a mess with those models.